# Fragment-based app using ViewPager (Android Studio Template) creates off-screen fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I created a new project in Android Studio that uses fragments and tabs to select a fragment.
So Android Studio created a project for me that uses a ViewPager to select the different fragments.

Unfortunately, **ViewPager will create off-screen fragments** and even trigger onResume() in the off-screen fragment !

This is a problem, since code in onResume() in fragment 2 depends on what a user does in fragment 1.

I've tried setting `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);` but this doesn't seem to have any effect, the neighboring fragment is still called with onResume() before it's actually shown.

**QUESTION**

What callback is triggered in a Fragment when it's actually shown?
Otherwise, how can I set it up so that I can adjust the UI in fragment 2 depending on what the user did in Fragment 1 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle AsyncTask's in ActionBarActivity Fragments when ViewPager is used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21914808/how-to-handle-asynctasks-in-actionbaractivity-fragments-when-viewpager-is-used)

Answer (score 0):

you can use setOnPageChangeListener() like this

```
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            // TO DO 

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
    });
```

Comment: yeah, right now onPageSelected() contains `actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);` I suppose at this point call something like `Fragment2.reinitUI()` ?

Comment: I found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21914808/how-to-handle-asynctasks-in-actionbaractivity-fragments-when-viewpager-is-used/24386516#24386516  Google should have improved their template since UI's are likely dynamic, not static slideshows.